# How to bottom align Button in the popup?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to bottom align button in the popup ?

here is my tried code, but its giving some space from bottom.
I have used listview to build up popup

```
     onPressed: () {
         // Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(homePageTag);
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    content: Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: ListView(
                        shrinkWrap: true,//This tells items to be put in center
                        children: <Widget>[

                          FlatButton(
                              //padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                              color: appGreenColor,
                              child: Text("UPDATE", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                              onPressed: () {

                              },
                            ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });
        },
```

Looking for this-  https://ibb.co/19k2ty7
& getting this - https://ibb.co/h7KwXbn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    Color myColor = Color(0xff00bfa5);

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: "Rounde Alert Box",
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: myColor,
            title: Text("Rounded Alert Box"),
            ),
            body: RoundedAlertBox(),
        ),
        );
    }
    }

    class RoundedAlertBox extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _RoundedAlertBoxState createState() => _RoundedAlertBoxState();
    }

    class _RoundedAlertBoxState extends State<RoundedAlertBox> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: openAlertBox,
            color: myColor,
            child: Text(
            "Open Alert Box",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
        ),
        );
    }

    openAlertBox() {
        return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0))),
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                content: Container(
                width: 300.0,
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                            "Rate",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                        ),
                        Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                                Icons.star_border,
                                color: myColor,
                                size: 30.0,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                                Icons.star_border,
                                color: myColor,
                                size: 30.0,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                                Icons.star_border,
                                color: myColor,
                                size: 30.0,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                                Icons.star_border,
                                color: myColor,
                                size: 30.0,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                                Icons.star_border,
                                color: myColor,
                                size: 30.0,
                            ),
                            ],
                        ),
                        ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                    ),
                    Divider(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        height: 4.0,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                        child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Add Review",
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                        ),
                        maxLines: 8,
                        ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                        child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: myColor,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(32.0),
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(32.0)),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                            "Rate Product",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    ],
                ),
                ),
            );
            });
    }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: how you printed card on your stackoverflow profile ?

Comment: Just upload as image, there is option.

Comment: Yes got it by inspecting https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1600058.png

Comment: Which book/ tutorial/website you recommend for flutter learn ?

Comment: Refere official doc only, because it update day by day, just choose topic on it and search you will gets lots of demo and ideas.

Comment: please help this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57671704/how-to-put-view-above-the-list-view