# How to put view above the list view?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a listview which is equally divided into two parts(act as a background) How can i put a view above it( 100*100 w*h )?(This box should center align & top of root)

here is my tried code -

```
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: ((context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).size.width),
              height: ((context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).size.height)/2,
              color: darkGreen,
            ),
          //  SizedBox(width: 10,),
            Container(
              width: ((context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).size.width),
              height: ((context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).size.height)/2,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need this line:

```dart
((context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).size.width)
```

you can replace it with:

```dart
double.infinity
```

and it will take the maximum width the parent `Widget` can allow.

as for your question, you can wrap your `ListView` in a `Stack`:

```dart
Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height:
                    ((context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).size.height) / 2,
                color: darkGreen,
              ),
              //  SizedBox(width: 10,),
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height:
                    ((context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).size.height) / 2,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ],
          ),

          //place your desired widget here
        ],
      ),
    ),
```